# How to import custom package in JAVA in PLAY framework

Tags: java, playframework

I have created a java project using PLAY framework.
But when I added some external package of another project It gives Compilation  error.
I have also added all the relevant jars required.And also make my original project dependent on the project which has MyUtils package.

"error: package MyUtils does not exist"

How to fix this?
[image: Compilation error]

Comment: I am using Windows 8 as my OS and eclipse JUNO as my IDE

Comment: Is MyUtils a class or package?

Comment: You probably should use full qualified name of the class, like com.verma.manish.MyUtils.test (or something), also try to eclipsify your project again, maybe then the Eclipse will help you to find you that path

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about projects and dependencies as if you were working on eclipse or similar, and I believe I can guess what you're doing, which will make it compile in eclipse, but is not related to how it will work once you run play on its own.

Make sure that you have the jar that contains the MyUtils package in the **lib** dir of your project.

Comment: I was having same issue: I wrote "libs" instead of "lib" (note extra S)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to create lib folder and add your jar to that directory?
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/SBTDependencies